# Google Cloud Run - Disabling automatic retry on HttpStatus 500 response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I run Spring boots service on Cloud Run.
The webserver is Firebase Hosting.

If a Endpoint on a pod answers a HttpResponse with 500 status, it seems that it is automatically retries 1 time after 2/3 seconds.
This is usually the default behaviour of Istio.

Well, is it possible to disable that on Cloud Run ?
The turnaround is to reply error 4xx instead of 5xx (that works, I tried :) ), but this is not elegant...

I did not find any info in GCP docs. The GUI only allows traffic management in terms of %age per prod.

Did anyone find a solution ?

Thanks !

Chenav

Comment: Returning a 500 series error means your code/service crashed. That is not elegant either.

Comment: How are you testing? With your browser?

Comment: Guillaume, Testing with browser and e2e tests.
Spent several hours in testing the different error codes, seems to occur only on 500 responses
Read GCP Cloud Run docs, I did not see it mentionned
Actually, this is a default Istio setting and I think that's what is happening behind the scene

@John Regarding the 500 error, when your pod relies on external webservices, 500 may occur as unavailability ends into server errors... some use cases don't need retries in that case and that's why you have the hand on Istio setting outside managed services. Thanks for your comment :)
--> 500 is legit

Comment: If you must return a 5xx error, then return `503 Service Unavailable`. Review what 500 means: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500